# Unusual Java behavior - why does this work?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

I've found some interesting behavior... I can't decide if it's a bug or incompetence, but currently leaning towards incompetence.

This code will not enter the loop, even if there are messages waiting:

```
Message msg;
while ((msg = consumer.receiveNoWait()) != null) {
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

This code DOES enter the loop, notice the null assignment:

```
Message msg = null;
while ((msg = consumer.receiveNoWait()) != null) {
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

This code is running on Glassfish 3.1.1b10 HotSpot 1.6_26 on Windows 32bit. I can't think of an explanation why the first block doesn't work!

EDIT/UPDATE July 13, 2011:

First, I began stopping the Glassfish domain and deleting it between deploys per request, and this still occurs :)

Second, I cannot sync on Destination or Consumer, as this is Java EE code. But, I can assure there are messages available. There's about 500 of them available an no consumers. In fact, creating a QueueBrowser tells me there's messages available!

Third, this program prints "WORKS!" every time!!! ARGH!!!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object obj;

    if ((obj = getNotNull()) != null) {
        System.out.println("worked!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("failed!");
    }
}

static Object getNotNull() {
    return new Object();
}
```

Lastly, I was speaking about my own incompetence. ;)

Comment: It depends on `consumer.receiveNoWait()`. Try `System.out.println(consumer.receiveNoWait() == null)`

Comment: Site note to any overzealous mods: This does **not** (I repeat: **not**) belong on CGSE. Just in case you're considering a migration due to the presence of the word »challenge«. Thank you on behalf of the CGSE users.

Comment: If you thought that was bad, I can make the JIT from Microsoft's VM for Java throw an impossible null pointer exception. (The VM for Java itself does not exhibit the bug, which proves that it's the JIT's fault.)

Comment: the code is same, the issue is in the `receiveNoWait()` and the availability of any message in the queue. Quite simple: if poll a queue and it's empty the effect will be exactly the same.

Comment: @edutesoy Incompetence of whom* ;)

Comment: @Ryan, shit thanks! +1 for the free english lesson :) I sincerely appreciate it, i'm not going to forget this one!

Comment: @Ryan: Is it really `whom`? Why? I thought `whom` was for objects and `who` was for subjects...

Comment: edutesoy: codegolf.stackexchange.com. Recently a few questions were moved there due to bad wording that didn't belong there.

Comment: What happens when you attach a debugger?

Comment: Where do you get the consumer from, and how do you know that there are messages "immediately available" for that consumer? (http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html#receiveNoWait())

Comment: @mehrdad - you are exactly correct.  Whom is used for objects and who for subjects (frequently confused).  In this case, you are asking about the target of incompetence, being the object in this question.  When in doubt, figure out if you can introduce "he" or "him" in the sentence.  If you use "he", you use who; "him" you use whom :)

Comment: @Ryan: I thought of it more as the person who *has* the incompetence, so I thought it might be a subject; cool! I didn't know the he/him thing, that's helpful, thanks.

Comment: is it possible to recreate this behavior in a unit test that uses a mock consumer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ryan said, seems like a race condition. The bytecodes for both codes are the same, with the exception of an extra "astore":

```
public static void code1()   throws javax.jms.JMSException;
  Code:
   0:   getstatic   #2; //Field consumer:Ljavax/jms/MessageConsumer;
   3:   invokeinterface #3,  1; //InterfaceMethod javax/jms/MessageConsumer.receiveNoWait:()Ljavax/jms/Message;
   8:   dup
   9:   astore_0
   10:  ifnull  23
   13:  getstatic   #4; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   16:  aload_0
   17:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   20:  goto    0
   23:  return

public static void code2()   throws javax.jms.JMSException;
  Code:
   0:   aconst_null
   1:   astore_0
   2:   getstatic   #2; //Field consumer:Ljavax/jms/MessageConsumer;
   5:   invokeinterface #3,  1; //InterfaceMethod javax/jms/MessageConsumer.receiveNoWait:()Ljavax/jms/Message;
   10:  dup
   11:  astore_0
   12:  ifnull  25
   15:  getstatic   #4; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   18:  aload_0
   19:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   22:  goto    2
   25:  return

}
```

If you want to test this theory, try this code:

```
Message msg;
String dummy = null;
while ((msg = consumer.receiveNoWait()) != null) {
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

It's a noop, but the bytecode is almost the same as the second code (changes "astore_0" to "astore_1").

BTW, I had horrible results with "receiveNoWait". I prefer "receive(smallTimeout)", to avoid buffer underruns or such.

Comment: I get same affect using javap with my full blown code!!! Something strange is happening to the code when it's deployed to glassfish, and some sort of race develops. Since I can't disassemble the stub code... i guess i'll never know! But, I'll give you the points for answering since you're the closest.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a race condition to me.  Declaration of objects without instantiation will always result in null values.  You may believe there are Messages waiting for you in the first case, but I bet there aren't.  Before the conditional loop, print out the number of objects there are and verify the resulting behavior.  If you are in a multi-threaded situation, synchronize on the Message queue if necessary to facilitate this.  I am betting it works exactly as expected.

Comment: actually i believe it's just a persistent queue and the data is inserted after 'receiveNoWait', so the next time it's available.

Comment: @bestsss this does not explains why it only works when the variable is initialized with "null"

Answer (score 0):

My money is on you weren't running the code you thought you were. You mention "running on Glassfish 3.1.1b10 ", so presumably not much in the way of unit testing and therefore the ability to pinpoint where the error is becomes more difficult.

There are a couple possibilities that might possibly make a difference in some bizarre edge case.

- It makes a subtle change to class loading order, and you do something dodgy in static initialisation. I'm not even sure if it does make a difference to class loading order.
- The `null` assignment clobbers a reference on the stack, which allows an object to be be garbage collected that references an object that is used with a weak/soft/phantom/finaliser reference, or perhaps just changes memory allocation timings and disturbs a race condition.

Comment: I think this is a decent explanation, but I'm fairly certain I've covered this. Just to be sure, I will delete the glassfish domain between trying the two pieces of code, which will 100% guarantee there is not crosstalk between the deployments. I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: still present after deleting the domain!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to provide what consumer oject may be and what does receiveNoWait() may be?

Comment: It's the JMS API, see here: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/package-frame.html